# Google Apps Script "Service using too much computer time for one day" Error

Tags: google-apps-script

I have begun to get this error just this week. I checked [My Executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions) on Google Apps Script dashboard. But I do not see any scripts that are taking anywhere near the [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas) of Triggers total run time, which is 90 min / day for consumer accounts. This error tends to happen near midnight pacific time. So I am thinking near the end of the 24 hour quota period. Does anyone know what recent change Google has made that is causing this error? If I knew what Google changed, I could adjust my scripts to avoid the error.

I checked some other answers but they were not helpful because this seems to be a recent change that Google made.

Comment: Have you heard of Google changing something or is it just a supposition?

Comment: Someone else is using your account is a better explanation.

Comment: @JSmith it has happened in two of my accounts. Both in the last week. So I assumed it was something Google changed.

Comment: @I'-'I wouldn't this be shown in the my executions tab? All of the executions are ones I set up.

Comment: Did you uncheck "Ran as me" filter in the executions tab?

Comment: Happened again today.

Comment: I'm trying out g suite and not getting the error there. I'm not sure how these quotas are calculated.

Comment: Try changing your password